# Do all the snacks featured have real world counterparts?

Tags: dagashi-kashi

Watching Dagashi Kashi will surely make you want to try some of the snacks that the characters portray to be very yummy. Do all of the snacks featured in this series have real life versions?

Answer (score 11):

All of the products featured in the show are at least representative of real-life product that have existed, *in Japan*.

The products featured in the titles of the first two episodes are:

Episode 1:

- [Umaibo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umaib%C5%8D)
- [Potato Fry](http://news-act.com/archives/36831531.html)
- [Coffee Milk Candy](http://dagashido.arriveatonce.co.jp/boxsell/gumsbox/1A10802box.htm)
- [Young Donuts](http://miyataseika.co.jp/index.php/young/)

---

Episode 2:

- [Kinako-bou](http://ewatari.jp/?pid=5685170)
- [Namaiki Beer](http://www.excite.co.jp/News/bit/00091158603586.html)
- [Flute Ramune](http://www.coris.co.jp/products/cat01/)
- [Menko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menko), a game akin to [Pogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogs).

Much of the culture and novelty of Dagashi is rooted in Japanese culture, making it very hard for those out of Japan to appreciate.

Comment: What do you mean no-one picked it up? Funimation licensed it, and it's screening on the Australian site AnimeLab.

Comment: Okay I rescinded my last sentence in light of what you said.